# Java generic observer

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

I have 2 object: `Protocol` and `Server`. The first one is notifying `Server` with different objects and `Server` should perform action depending on type of object. So, perfect option for me is:

```
// Server.java
public Server implements IObserver {
    public void onAction(ActionObjectOne o) {
        //do magic
    }
    public void onAction(ActionObjectTwo o) {
        //do magic
    }
    ....
}
```

```
// Protocol.java
public Protocol extends AObservable {
   // ....
   notifyObservers(ActionObjectOne one);
   // ...
}
```

So i decided that it is a job for observer pattern.

```
public interface IObserver {
    <T extends IAction> void onAction(T action);
}
```

```
public class Server implements IObserver {
    @Override
    public <AuthAction> void onAction(AuthAction action) {
        // HERE IS A PROBLEM
    }
}
```

```
public class AuthAction extends Action; // Action implements IAction - a flag-interface
```

Errors are in `Server`:

- The method onAction(AuthAction) of type Server must override or
  implement a supertype method
- The type parameter AuthAction is hiding the type AuthAction

So, how to implement my "perfect option" =)?

Comment: FYI We generally don't prefix our abstract classes and interfaces with `A` and `I` in Java. You're free to do whatever you want of course.

Comment: You're using AuthAuction as a type variable, not as a type argument.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis don't understand what are you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    try {
        Method update = getClass().getMethod("onAction", arg.getClass());
        update.invoke(this, arg);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        LOGGER.error("No onAction for <" + arg.getClass().getSimpleName() + "> action.");
        LOGGER.catching(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.catching(e);
    }
}
```

`and then:`

```
public void onAction (AuthAction action) {
        System.out.println("New user incoming!");
    }
```

Comment: Careful with reflective solutions. If your argument is not of the appropriate type, exceptions will be thrown. You also don't gain. The issue here isn't the delegation to a method, it's the actual logic for each different type of `Action`.

Comment: exceptions are not a problem here and server shouldn't process Actions it doesn't know. anyway, it's a best solution i've found(

Answer (score 1):

In the following syntax

```
public <AuthAction> void onAction(AuthAction action) {
```

the expression `AuthAction` is a type variable, not a type argument. The code above is equivalent to

```
public <T> void onAction(T action) {
```

So you can therefore see how your `Server` class is not implementing `IObserver`'s method. I would instead make `IObserver` a generic interface and implement it like so

```
public interface IObserver<T extends IAction> {
    void onAction(T action);
}

class Server implements IObserver<AuthAction> {
    @Override
    public  void onAction(AuthAction action) {
    }

}
```

Comment: the problem is that I can't use generic in IObserver, coz `Server` can be notified not only with `AuthAction`, but with `DisconnectAction`, `MessageAction` etc...so i need `onAction(AuthAction a)`, `onAction(DisconnectAction a)`, `onAction(MessageAction a)` etc...

Comment: @wingsofovnia The only way to provide a type argument to a generic method is to do it when invoking the method. You're going to have to change your design altogether. Whoever is invoking `Server#onAction(..)` should know what action they are passing. Do you do different logic for each type of `Action`? If yes, overload the method.

Comment: yes, i have different logic for `IAction`s. I can overload method, but how to describe `IObserver` interface?

Comment: @wingsofovnia Not with generics, with specific overloaded method.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your application, I'd probably say yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is the set of `IAction`s finite, unchanging, and manageable?  If so, your Observer is more like a Visitor and requires an overload for every one of the known actions.

If the set of `IAction`s is not all of those things, but the caller knows what kind of `IAction` is being passed in statically, your `IObserver` interface as defined is correct.  That is, an implementer of the interface (such as `Server`) should *dynamically* react to the specific `IAction` class, using any of a number of extremely ugly choices in Java to do so.

```
public interface IObserver {
    void < T extends IAction > onAction( T action );
}
public class Server implements IObserver {
    @Override public void < T extends IAction > onAction( T action ) {
        // ugliness, e.g. if-ladders based on instanceof
    }
}
```

I don't think that buys you very much.

If the caller does not know which `IAction` is going to be used at runtime, then your only choice is

```
public interface IObserver {
    void onAction( IAction action );
}
public class Server implements IObserver {
    @Override public void onAction( IAction action ) {
        // ugliness, e.g. if-ladders based on instanceof
    }
}
```

whose implementation will look the same as in the previous example.